# Trying to swap buttons to certain rectangles

Tags: java, button, javafx, swap, shuffle

So, I'm trying to make a certain kind of matching game.

Basically, there's 6 color-coded rectangles. In order, they are: red, blue, green, yellow, orange, and purple.

There are buttons of the same color that are randomly arranged so that they are mismatched. Red button is in the green rectangle, Orange button in the yellow rectangle, etc.

When you click on the button, say, red button. The button would then be sent to the red rectangle, but it would swap its current position with whatever button is currently on red.

However, I'm not sure how to do it exactly. I tried making it swap within the array inside of a for loop with a dummy print method, but that doesn't seem to work. What would I need to do? Would I need to make a method to return whatever button was on the first spot in the array?

I've tried looking around for swap methods in JavaFX for buttons specifically, but I couldn't find anything substantial.

If you want to take a look at my code, I'll link it here. https://pastebin.com/gEG5FVWT

Also, occasionally when I try to run the program, there's a chance that I get an error and the program fails to launch. Relaunching seems to fix this.

I'm going to paste the part of the code that I need help with, and I'll provide some context:

I have the buttons red, blue, green, yellow, orange, and purple put into an array `buttons[]` with an index of 0-5.
I tried using a swap array line and I tried using the linear search feature, but neither went anywhere.

`0` is the position of the button `red.`
When clicking red button, it should swap red to the red rectangle. There's no easy way to do this since the rectangles are constructed separately and *not* in any group or array or anything like that.

```
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
          int key = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
              if (0 == buttons[i]) {
                key = i;
              System.out.println(key);
              }
          }         
     int temp = buttons[0];
      buttons[0] = 0;
      buttons[key] = temp;
      }
    });
```

So what ends up happening is... nothing. It prints out key once when pressing it, then it continues to print out 0 on a line after that. I'm not sure what to from here, but I'd need an action event for each button.

Main thing is: I need the buttons to actually swap to their correct places once clicked on.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

I would probably store your button locations in an array, with each index representing a rectangle. {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} would represent each button on their corresponding rectangle and {1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5} meaning the red and blue buttons are swapped. When a button is pressed, you could change the colors of the buttons, instead of actually changing their location. So for example if you started with {1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, by pressing the red button the first button (since red is index 0) would change color to red and the button you clicked would change color to whatever was in the 0 index, in this case, 1 (blue). After changing the colors of those two buttons, mirror this switch in the array so that the state of the game is properly recorded.